# get duplicate value from single array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

i am new in iOS and trying some stuff can u guys please help me. Thanks for the help

```
let values = ["sid","sid","tarun","nitesh"]
```

output must be:

```
["sid","sid"]
```

Comment: What did you try so far and what exactly doesn't work with the approach you've taken?

Comment: You surely tried *something.* Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that it does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: i tried with filter and contains but didn't get output what i need

Comment: What's your expected output when more than one word duplicate in array?

Comment: Why do you need the output like that? What are you going to do with it? What happens when there are three or more "sid"s?

Comment: if there are three sid in an array so it will come ["sid","sid","sid"]

Comment: So your question is how to use filter then?

Comment: yes i want duplicate values

Comment: in filter the value `$0`  is your current value and then you compare it to what you want to filter which in your case is `"sid"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check each element's count in the array and if the count is greater than 1 append in the result array

```
let values = ["sid","sid","tarun","nitesh","nitesh"]
var result = [String]()
values.forEach { value in
    if values.filter({ $0 == value }).count > 1 {
        result.append(value)
    }
}
print(result)//["sid", "sid", "nitesh", "nitesh"]
```

OR

```
let result = values.filter { value in values.filter({ $0 == value }).count > 1  }
print(result)
```

Comment: More generic way

`func findDuplicate<T: Hashable>(myArray: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    var result = Array<T>()
    for item in myArray {
        if myArray.filter({ $0 == item }).count > 1 {
            result.append(item)
        }
    }
    return result
}`

Answer (score 2):

An efficient solution is to create a “word count” or “histogram” first. The array is traversed once, and a dictionary is updated for each value:

```
let values = ["sid", "sid", "tarun", "nitesh"]

let wordcount = values.reduce(into: [:]) { (dict, value) in
    dict[value, default: 0] += 1
}
```

In your example that would be the dictionary `["nitesh": 1, "sid": 2, "tarun": 1]`.

Then use that dictionary to filter the array, and keep only entries with a word count greater than one. This requires another traversal of the array:

```
let duplicates = values.filter { wordcount[$0, default: 0] > 1 }
print(duplicates) // ["sid", "sid"]
```

The total complexity is *linear* in the number of array elements.